# Pseudo elemnt "before" onhover does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I want to create a faq page, I found a sample and tried to customize it and learn from it. Whenever I hover over the menu items, a little green rectangle should appear on the left side of the menu. But this does not happen in my code, am I missing anything?
The HTML Code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //update these values if you change these breakpoints in the style.css file (or _layout.scss if you use SASS)
  var MqM = 768,
    MqL = 1024;

  var faqsSections = $('.cd-faq-group'),
    faqTrigger = $('.cd-faq-trigger'),
    faqsContainer = $('.cd-faq-items'),
    faqsCategoriesContainer = $('.cd-faq-categories'),
    faqsCategories = faqsCategoriesContainer.find('a'),
    closeFaqsContainer = $('.cd-close-panel');

  //select a faq section 
  faqsCategories.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var selectedHref = $(this).attr('href'),
      target = $(selectedHref);
    if ($(window).width() < MqM) {
      faqsContainer.scrollTop(0).addClass('slide-in').children('ul').removeClass('selected').end().children(selectedHref).addClass('selected');
      closeFaqsContainer.addClass('move-left');
      $('body').addClass('cd-overlay');
    } else {
      $('body,html').animate({
        'scrollTop': target.offset().top - 19
      }, 200);
    }
  });

  //close faq lateral panel - mobile only
  $('body').bind('click touchstart', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('body.cd-overlay') || $(event.target).is('.cd-close-panel')) {
      closePanel(event);
    }
  });
  faqsContainer.on('swiperight', function(event) {
    closePanel(event);
  });

  //show faq content clicking on faqTrigger
  faqTrigger.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.cd-faq-content').slideToggle(200).end().parent('li').toggleClass('content-visible');
  });

  //update category sidebar while scrolling
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).width() > MqL) {
      (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ? updateCategory(): window.requestAnimationFrame(updateCategory);
    }
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= MqL) {
      faqsCategoriesContainer.removeClass('is-fixed').css({
        '-moz-transform': 'translateY(0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateY(0)',
        '-o-transform': 'translateY(0)',
        'transform': 'translateY(0)',
      });
    }
    if (faqsCategoriesContainer.hasClass('is-fixed')) {
      faqsCategoriesContainer.css({
        'left': faqsContainer.offset().left,
      });
    }
  });

  function closePanel(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    faqsContainer.removeClass('slide-in').find('li').show();
    closeFaqsContainer.removeClass('move-left');
    $('body').removeClass('cd-overlay');
  }

  function updateCategory() {
    updateCategoryPosition();
    updateSelectedCategory();
  }

  function updateCategoryPosition() {
    var top = $('.cd-faq').offset().top,
      height = jQuery('.cd-faq').height() - jQuery('.cd-faq-categories').height(),
      margin = 20;
    if (top - margin <= $(window).scrollTop() && top - margin + height > $(window).scrollTop()) {
      var leftValue = faqsCategoriesContainer.offset().left,
        widthValue = faqsCategoriesContainer.width();
      faqsCategoriesContainer.addClass('is-fixed').css({
        'left': leftValue,
        'top': margin,
        '-moz-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
        '-o-transform': 'translateZ(0)',
        'transform': 'translateZ(0)',
      });
    } else if (top - margin + height <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
      var delta = top - margin + height - $(window).scrollTop();
      faqsCategoriesContainer.css({
        '-moz-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY(' + delta + 'px)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY(' + delta + 'px)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY(' + delta + 'px)',
        '-o-transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY(' + delta + 'px)',
        'transform': 'translateZ(0) translateY(' + delta + 'px)',
      });
    } else {
      faqsCategoriesContainer.removeClass('is-fixed').css({
        'left': 0,
        'top': 0,
      });
    }
  }

  function updateSelectedCategory() {
    faqsSections.each(function() {
      var actual = $(this),
        margin = parseInt($('.cd-faq-title').eq(1).css('marginTop').replace('px', '')),
        activeCategory = $('.cd-faq-categories a[href="#' + actual.attr('id') + '"]'),
        topSection = (activeCategory.parent('li').is(':first-child')) ? 0 : Math.round(actual.offset().top);

      if ((topSection - 20 <= $(window).scrollTop()) && (Math.round(actual.offset().top) + actual.height() + margin - 20 > $(window).scrollTop())) {
        activeCategory.addClass('selected');
      } else {
        activeCategory.removeClass('selected');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
*, *::after, *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::after, *::before {
  content: '';
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #4e5359;
  background-color: #f3f3f5;
}
body::after {
  /* overlay layer visible on small devices when the right panel slides in */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(78, 83, 89, 0.8);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}
body.cd-overlay::after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body::after {
    display: none;
  }
}

a {
  color: #a9c056;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  line-height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #a9c056;
}
header h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  header {
    height: 240px;
    line-height: 240px;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}

.cd-faq {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.cd-faq:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-faq {
    position: relative;
    margin: 4em auto;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

.cd-faq-categories a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 28px 0 16px;
  background-color: #4e5359;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #ffffff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555b61;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.cd-faq-categories a::before, .cd-faq-categories a::after {
  /* plus icon on the right */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #7f868e;
}
.cd-faq-categories a::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.cd-faq-categories li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-faq-categories {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  }
  .cd-faq-categories a {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s, padding 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s, padding 0.2s;
    transition: background 0.2s, padding 0.2s;
  }
  .cd-faq-categories a::before, .cd-faq-categories a::after {
    display: none;
  }
  .no-touch .cd-faq-categories a:hover {
    background: #555b61;
  }
  .no-js .cd-faq-categories {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-faq-categories {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .cd-faq-categories a::before {
    /* decorative rectangle on the left visible for the selected item */
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #a9c056;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }
  .cd-faq-categories .selected {
    background: #42464b !important;
  }
  .cd-faq-categories .selected::before {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .cd-faq-categories.is-fixed {
    /* top and left value assigned in jQuery */
    position: fixed;
  }
  .no-js .cd-faq-categories {
    position: relative;
  }
}

.cd-faq-items {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 5% 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.cd-faq-items.slide-in {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0%);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0%);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0%);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0%);
}
.no-js .cd-faq-items {
  position: static;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-faq-items {
    position: static;
    height: auto;
    width: 78%;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
    transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-faq-items {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 220px;
  }
  .no-js .cd-faq-items {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

.cd-close-panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  right: -100%;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: right 0.4s;
  transition: right 0.4s;
}
.cd-close-panel::before, .cd-close-panel::after {
  /* close icon in CSS */
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 18px;
  background: #6c7d8e;
}
.cd-close-panel::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cd-close-panel::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.cd-close-panel.move-left {
  right: 2%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-close-panel {
    display: none;
  }
}

.cd-faq-group {
  /* hide group not selected */
  display: none;
}
.cd-faq-group.selected {
  display: block;
}
.cd-faq-group .cd-faq-title {
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.no-touch .cd-faq-group .cd-faq-title:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.cd-faq-group .cd-faq-title h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #bbbbc7;
}
.no-js .cd-faq-group {
  display: block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-faq-group {
    /* all groups visible */
    display: block;
  }
  .cd-faq-group > li {
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  }
  .no-touch .cd-faq-group > li:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(108, 125, 142, 0.3);
  }
  .cd-faq-group .cd-faq-title {
    margin: 2em 0 1em;
  }
  .cd-faq-group:first-child .cd-faq-title {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.cd-faq-trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 1.6em 0 .4em;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-faq-trigger {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 24px 72px 24px 24px;
  }
  .cd-faq-trigger::before, .cd-faq-trigger::after {
    /* arrow icon on the right */
    position: absolute;
    right: 24px;
    top: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    width: 13px;
    background: #cfdca0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
  }
  .cd-faq-trigger::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    right: 32px;
  }
  .cd-faq-trigger::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .content-visible .cd-faq-trigger::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .content-visible .cd-faq-trigger::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

.cd-faq-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #6c7d8e;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-faq-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 0 24px 30px;
  }
  .cd-faq-content p {
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
  .no-js .cd-faq-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title</title>
 <!-- the jQuery file that is included here -->
  <script src="main.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="cd-faq">
    <ul class="cd-faq-categories">
      <li><a class="selected" href="#basics">Basics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#mobile">Mobile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#account">Account</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="basics" class="cd-faq-group">
      <li class="cd-faq-title">
        <h2>Basics</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="#0">How do I change my password?             </a>
        <div class="cd-faq-content">
          <p>Lorem .</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="mobile" class="cd-faq-group">
      <li class="cd-faq-title">
        <h2>Mobile</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="#0">How does syncing work?</a>
        <div class="cd-faq-content">
          <p>Lorem </p>
        </div>
        <!-- cd-faq-content -->
        <a href="#0" class="cd-close-panel">Close</a>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please try to minimize the code you post for the part you need help with

Comment: I don't see any combo of `:before` with a `:hover` selector in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this codepen example.  Just as Michael has mentioned, you need to adhere the pseudo-selector with hover.

Ex.

```
.element:before:hover{transform:rotateX(180deg);}
```

https://codepen.io/larrygeams/pen/pdchG

Comment: thanks for your comment. Can you please tell me why do we need to have the following, when we do not have any effect on a:after, (we have the effect on a:hover: after)
        

    nav li a:after { 

      content: "";
      height: 100%; 
      left: 0; 
       top: 0; 
      width: 0px;  
      position: absolute; 
      transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; 
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; 
      z-index: -1;
}

Comment: Sorry. Not sure I understand what you're saying there.  Are you just curious why it's chained like that?